# Server-sent events (SSE) connection loss on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, server-sent-events, server-push

I'm working on a website where some events are broadcasted to the clients using SSE (EventSource API). When testing my site on the mobile version of Chrome for Android, I noticed the connection is lost when the channel is idle for about five minutes.

I used several Android devices, with different carriers and different browsers and the result is the same, no matter if the screen is on or off. Desktop Chrome seems to keep the connection alive for a longer time.

Couldn't find any info about this, and when trying to debug the issue, all I got was a TCP "FIN" packet received from the telephone IP address about 3 and a half minutes after the last event was sent.

EventSource's `onerror` event doesn't get fired so I can't know when the connection was dropped to initiate a new one.

Is there any way to avoid this problem or should I just send some fake message every 30 secs to prevent connection idling?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your connection was probably taken by a "push proxy" - a feature that is designed to improve battery life in phones.

Quote from "https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html":

> User agents running in controlled environments, e.g. browsers on
> mobile handsets tied to specific carriers, may offload the management
> of the connection to a proxy on the network. In such a situation, the
> user agent for the purposes of conformance is considered to include
> both the handset software and the network proxy.
>
> For example, a browser on a mobile device, after having established a
> connection, might detect that it is on a supporting network and
> request that a proxy server on the network take over the management of
> the connection. The timeline for such a situation might be as follows:
>
> 1. Browser connects to a remote HTTP server and requests the resource specified by the author in the EventSource constructor.
> 2. The server sends occasional messages.
> 3. In between two messages, the browser detects that it is idle except for the network activity involved in keeping the TCP connection alive,
>    and decides to switch to sleep mode to save power.
> 4. The browser disconnects from the server.
> 5. The browser contacts a service on the network, and requests that the service, a "push proxy", maintain the connection instead.
> 6. The "push proxy" service contacts the remote HTTP server and requests the resource specified by the author in the EventSource
>    constructor (possibly including a `Last-Event-ID` HTTP header, etc).
> 7. The browser allows the mobile device to go to sleep.
> 8. The server sends another message.
> 9. The "push proxy" service uses a technology such as OMA push to convey the event to the mobile device, which wakes only enough to
>    process the event and then returns to sleep.
>
> This can reduce the total data usage, and can therefore result in
> considerable power savings.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`retry`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#processField) field to establish the [reconnection time](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#concept-event-stream-reconnection-time) of `EventSource` instance

> - If the field name is "retry"
>
>   - If the field value consists of only ASCII digits, then interpret the field value as an integer in base ten, and set the event stream's
>       reconnection time to that integer. Otherwise, ignore the field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, guest! Unfortunately, sending a "retry" makes no difference: it's like the client drops the connection and makes nothing to establish it again.

Comment: Have you tried sending messages in a span less than five minutes?

Comment: Yes, if I'm sending messages, for example, every two minutes, the connection never drops. So I could be sending "keep-alive" messages every minute or so, but I wondered if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Am not presently able to test code on mobile Chrome. Not sure if the implementation at that version is intended to conserve battery? You could try defining a separate named event to keep the connection alive and send messages relevant to application to `message` event. Have you filed a [bug](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) report describing the issue?

Comment: I tried it on different Android devices, some of them connected via USB (just in case they were in powersave mode) but all behaved the same. Different Chrome versions, too. I wanted to gather some information before reporting a bug. About separate events, I found that SSE considers all lines begining with ":" as comments, so it looks like a convenient way to send these keepalive messages.